# Unable to add the Java API documentation to Eclipse lun?

Tags: selenium

Hi I want to add java Documentation in the selenium project but I am unable to add that into eclipse luna. Kindly help me out. I am getting errors as attached.

Error
location might be invalid,files 'package-list' and index.html that are typically available at the root of documents created by the Javadoc tool have not been found

Comment: Have you tried following the various blogs that have done this? I tried this link -> https://dumbitdude.com/how-to-attach-selenium-javadoc-in-eclipse/ and it worked for me.

Comment: Note that Eclipse Luna is now 8 years and 18 releases old.